# GFS2 as shared storage for MySQL cluster with active active setting

Tags: mysql, configuration, clustering, mysql-5.7

I am using MySQL 5.7 on RHEL 7.1. For cluster management I am using Pacemaker and corosync. For shared storage, I am using GFS2 file system with iSCSI server

I am trying to implement MySQL active-active cluster (both nodes running at the same time). I have two nodes with MySQL server running. I am not able to give same data directory (shared storage) for both the nodes.

I tried to change the data directory in `my.cnf` file. After that the service didn't start. Currently, I am using the default storage engine i.e. InnoDB storage engine.

Is this a problem of the underlying storage engine or something else we need to change in the configuration?

Comment: Define "cluster".  NDB Cluster?  Galera Cluster?  Something else?

Answer (score 1):

Two *instances* of mysqld *must not* use the *same* data files.  The code is not designed to handle unexpected changes to the file, which will happen by the other instance.

(I assume you are talking about Master-Master replication when you say "cluster"?)